# Ember working with OData

Tags: ember.js, odata, breeze

Are there any examples of Ember working with an OData persistence layer for the client, such as Breeze.js. Can Ember or Breeze experts chime in to provide their knowledge about using the 2 frameworks jointly?

Comment: Are you using Handlebars?  Wouldn't your question more effectively e 'Using Handlebars.js with Breeze.js' instead of Ember?  http://www.breezejs.com/samples/car-bones

Comment: Not so. I would like a flow for working with an oData supporting persistence layer against my Ember models.

Comment: @izbz,
I think my reply **[here][1]** anwers this, no?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168772/ember-data-and-northwind-odata/19338654#19338654

Answer (score 0):

There is an OData adapter and serializer on [GitHub](https://github.com/lozjackson/ember-odata) although it currently only supports GET and PUT.