# Ember Data and Northwind OData

Tags: ember.js, odata, ember-data

Could Ember-Data b3+ be used for work against a service like this, http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc. If so, could anyone provide an example on how to use it to read OData.

For example a JSBin showing a list of customers where a customer list item can navigate to the orders of a clicked customer

I think this would be a great boon for developers working against different data protocols to wrap their heads around how to wire up an Ember application with Ember-Data.

I've done this with fixtures but just couldn't really wire it up with actual server data.

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit

Since I wrote this, I have abandoned Ember and fell back to angular for my SPA data apps. The main reason behind this is `Ember Set` which you should use for Ember to wire up all its binding internals.

Unfortunately, this is not compatible with most libs like Jaydata or Breeze. At least not when you wish to make changes/saves to your entity service.

Jaydata and Breeze both use a propertyChanged property to monitor changes to your entity and Ember will prevent these changes with a `You should use Ember Set` error.

I could probably have written some sort of adapter to overcome this problem but really I didn't have time and I use a library "Ember" to make my life easier... not to have headaches on basics such as Data Service Queries.

So... I really love Ember, but unfortunately as long as they dont enhance "Ember Data" or drastically change the Ember Set policy, I can't use it!

Basically, if you plan to use a data library (JayData, Breeze) to update a backend...

**DON'T USE EMBER!**

#### Original

I had a look (very quickly!) at ember-data and wasnt thrilled really! It looks promising for Standard REST service which IMHO is not WCF's case.

I ended up using JayData for that purpose and I must say it integrates very well with Ember.

here is a quick snippet to get you going:

```
//Instanciate the Ember APP
App = Ember.Application.create();

//Tell the APP to initialize but to wait before launching
App.deferReadiness();

//Setup your JayData Store
//Entities.EntityModel was generated by JaySvcUtil
App.myStore = new Entities.EntityModel({
    name: 'oData',
    oDataServiceHost: <YOUR_WCF_ENDPOINT_URL>
});

//Create your route and populate model data
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        //This passes the toArray() promise to the model
        return App.myStore.People.orderBy('it.Name').toArray();
    }
});

//When JayData Store is ready, Fire the App
App.myStore.onReady(function () {
      App.advanceReadiness();
});
```

Ember Route Model actually handles the promise given by JayData which allows us to just pass the query. see: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/#toc_the-router-pauses-for-promises

Comment: This is really cool. We do not have an emberjs integration yet, have've just released one for AngularJs but I hope to have EmberJS integration, too!

Comment: @GaborDolla, it would be great indeed! though its not difficult to get it going without integration.

Comment: A custom ember-data adapter would probably solve this, though I haven't checked the docs of the service mentioned above.